# Unable to proxy_pass mailcather with nginx

Tags: nginx, mailcatcher

I have following nginx conf

```
upstream domain1 {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
  server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}




server {
  listen   80;
  server_name demo.domain.com;

  root   /var/apps/myapp/public;

  location / {
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;

                if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
                                 rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
                }

                if (-f $request_filename.html) {
                                 rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
                }

                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                                 proxy_pass http://domain1;
                                 break;
                }
  }

 location /mail_us1 {
                proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:1080;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
 }


}
```

I'm trying to set up [mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/) on my server (mailcatcher running at `1080` port)

With my limited experience in nginx, I was assuming that the following directive would work good

```
 location /mail_us1 {
                    proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:1080;
                    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     }
```

But unfortunately I'm not able to get the desired output and I keeping getting landed on nginx pages that states

```
No Dice

The message you were looking for does not exist, or doesn't have content of this type.
```

Can Any one tell me what wrong I'm doing

**Note:**

```
- curl http://localhost:1080 (work )

- iptables -L (is empty)
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
location /mailcatcher {
  rewrite /mailcatcher/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://mailcatcher/;
}

location ~ ^/assets {
  proxy_pass http://mailcatcher;
}

location ~ ^/messages {
  proxy_pass http://mailcatcher;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

Comment: Are you doing anything with the hosts file? how are you setting what `http://mailcatcher` is?